# Redirecting to another HTML page doesn't work inside Javascript form submit event listener

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the JS code:

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      const map_not_uploaded = document.getElementById("map").value == "";
      const bugs_not_uploaded = (document.getElementById("bug1").value == "") || (document.getElementById("bug2").value == "");

      if (map_not_uploaded) {
            alert("Must upload map file");
            e.preventDefault();
      }
      else if (bugs_not_uploaded) {
            alert("Must upload both bug files");
            e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
            window.location.href = "new.html";
      }
});
```

`

After submitting the form, it checks correctly if the files were inputted,i.e. it displays the alerts. However, after correct inputs it doesnt't redirect to new.html.

Comment: Is `new.html` the only place the form should submit to? Does `new.html` execute the upload?  What's the action of the form? If you need to run code on the original html page first, then your `window.location.href` won't be executed because the page reloads first. You'll need to detect your form posting first, then redirect.

Comment: Because the form is submitting.  Note how you use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent that in your other cases, but you aren't using it in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `e.preventDefault()` at the top of the function.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const map_not_uploaded = document.getElementById("map").value == "";
  const bugs_not_uploaded = (document.getElementById("bug1").value == "") || (document.getElementById("bug2").value == "");

  if (map_not_uploaded) {
        alert("Must upload map file");
  }
  else if (bugs_not_uploaded) {
        alert("Must upload both bug files");
  }
  else {
        window.location.href = "new.html";
  }
  });
```